# Syntax Error on Token while doing the Android Time Picker Tutorial

Tags: java, android, token

So I've been following the time picker tutorial step by step to be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html).
Even though I went over the code again and again I can't spot where I supposedly made a mistake, I keep getting *"Syntax error on token "}", delete this token"* on the last token of the code file that you can see here:

```
public class ReportsActivity extends Activity {

//Set up variables for the time change button
private TextView mTimeDisplay;
private Button mPickTime;

private int mHour;
private int mMinute;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

//updates time displayed in textview
        private void updateDisplay(){
            mTimeDisplay.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                        .append(pad(mMinute)));
        }

        private static String pad(int c){
            if (c >= 10)
                return String.valueOf(c);
            else
                return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
        }



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report);



    //TIME CHANGE IMPLEMENTATION
    //Capturing View elements
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
    mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTime);

    //add click listener to the button
    mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    //current time
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //display current
    updateDisplay();    

}
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
                mHour = hourOfDay;
                mMinute = minute;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}
}



} //Here is where I get the error message
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last } . Its an extra one ..

Comment: No it's not, that was the obvious first thing I did.

Comment: One reason is this one but you might have others as well so whats the Error after removing that?

Comment: _The type new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(TimePicker, int, int)_   before the last @Override

Comment: can you edit your question and add the imports which you have used.

Comment: I have run through you example and I think you have not included this import `import android.widget.TimePicker;`. Inlclude it and remove the  last } as i already mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I was out for some minutes, actually that was the error, I don't really understand why I didn't have that import since I already went cmd+shift+O to auto import anything that could be missing, thanks a lot anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Glad its solved.then accept the answer as correct one by clicking on the right sign.